# Java and telnet - java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

Tags: java, osgi, telnet

I have an osgi framework and I want to connect to it via telnet in oder to send only one command - shutdown. That's why I don't want to use telnet libs like apache commons telnet.
My code:

```
System.out.println("I am stopping....");
Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",6666);
String command="shutdown";
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter( socket.getOutputStream(), true);
pw.print(command);
pw.flush();
socket.close();
pw.close();
```

It shutdowns osgi but on the side of osgi framework I get:

```
org.apache.felix.shell.remote [27] TerminalPrintStream::print()
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.apache.felix.shell.remote.TerminalPrintStream.print(TerminalPrintStream.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.shell.remote.TerminalPrintStream.println(TerminalPrintStream.java:63)
    at org.apache.felix.shell.remote.Shell.startFelixShell(Shell.java:130)
    at org.apache.felix.shell.remote.Shell.run(Shell.java:86)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How to fix it?

**EDIT 1:**

However the following code works without any exception (apache commons net).

```
TelnetClient telnet=new TelnetClient();
        try {
            telnet.connect("localhost", 6666);
            BufferedInputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(telnet.getInputStream());  
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(telnet.getOutputStream());  
            output.println("shutdown");
            output.flush();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ProgramManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: Use a library and make it work first.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen Everytning works if I do $telnet localhost 6666, shutdown. So I connect to framework and shutdown it. The problem is how to do it via java.

Comment: In your first example, you close the connection as soon as you sent the command. Probably felix remote shell wants to send some answer but it fails as you already closed the channel. In your second example, you do not close the channel at all (I guess there is a close function of telnet or you should close the streams). I suggest that in your first example read the answer of felix remote shell the socket only after it has arrived. Or simply read everything you can and you will notice that the socket will be closed by the server module after during its stop method.

Comment: @Balazs Zsoldos Thank you very much. I think you are right. You know, you helped me a lot of with osgi at stackoverflow. Thank you!

Comment: If that works, I make an answer from the comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not close the stream as soon as you sent the command as in this case the server cannot answer and throw the exception. You should read the stream of the socket until it is closed by the server. It will be closed as soon as the remote shell module is stopped.

Based on your code:

```
System.out.println("I am stopping....");
String command="shutdown";
try (Socket socket=new Socket("localhost",6666)) {
  OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
  InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
  out.write(command.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));

  // Wait until server closes the stream. Could be enhanced with some timeout
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, 
      Charset.defaultCharset())));
  String line = reader.readLine();
  while (line != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```